# Какое из чисел больше? и почему?

Tags: математика

Даны два числа. Какое из них больше? Число записано в виде степеней.

первое число: 2^ (2^ (2^ (99^ (3^ (3^ 20)))))

второе число: 99^ (99^ (99^ (98^ (3^ (3^ 20)))))

Comment: Вы верно думаете. А вопрос в чём, хотели бы получить строгое доказательство?

Comment: Есть такая хорошая функция - логарифм. Примените ее несколько раз и убедитесь...

Answer (score 4):

Из приведенных преобразований очевидно, что первое больше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]